# Product Model contains list of object - retrieving and displaying checkbox list incorrectly. MVC .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, razor, checkbox

I have my product class - edit view and edit get controller method. 
The view for the check boxes literally displays 'Name' instead of the ingredients name (ie. Cedarwood) - the checkbox should have some items 'selected' as they are set to true in the database.

**When debugging it the values are all there - the true/false values match with what is expected and the ingredient names are definitely being passed in.... just don't get why the view isn't showing it..

```
public class Product
  {

    public Product()
    {
        ProductImages = new List<ProductImage>();
        Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
        OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
    }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Blend { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Range(0.01, 100.00, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 0.01 and 100.00")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Product Art URL")]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string MainPhotoUrl { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LegendPhoto")]
    public byte[] LegendPhoto { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

}
```

controller:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        //get list of ingredients
        var ingredients = db.Ingredients.ToList();


        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
        product.Ingredients = db.Ingredients.ToList();
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(product); //product
    }
```

the view (the rest is fine just the checkbox for ingredients - so only showing it:

```
                   <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @for(var i = 0; i < Model.Ingredients.Count; i++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(ing => Model.Ingredients[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(ing => Model.Ingredients[i].Name)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Ingredients[i].IsSelected)
                        @Html.LabelFor(ing => Model.Ingredients[i].Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(ing => Model.Ingredients[i].IsSelected, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})

                    }
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is it this line which is the problem? `@Html.LabelFor(ing => Model.Ingredients[i].Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})` - not displaying the ingredient name properly? Is it definitely populated in your source data? And why have you also put that Name in a hidden field? Surely to update the DB, all you need to post back is the ID and the "IsSelected" property. You also don't need a hidden field for the IsSelected property - that's covered by the checkbox, and you'll end up trying to submit two different values for the same field name, which will give you problems.

Comment: Oh and `                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
` doesn't make a lot of sense. What would you expect a label of a List to look like?? Is it this line which is the issue, perhaps? It wasn't clear in your description.

Comment: Yeah you're right regarding the hidden fors - i was referencing another stackoverflow answer while i was trying to figure it out. Same with the un necessary to list in the controller method....

 The '@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"}) '   - basically displays [] Name [] Name etc etc - i expected it to be [] Cedarwood [] Lime [] Apple

Comment: the [] is meant to be a box...lol

Comment: Yeah you can't write out a List object directly to a string (which is what a label is). It doesn't know which properties of the objects in the list you intended to print.

Comment: Sorry, I copy and pasted the wrong labelfor in. No, the @Html.LabelFor(ing => Model.Ingredients[i].Name........) doesn't work - just returns 'Name' .

Don't understand why - as when debugging, I can see the proper ingredient name when hovering over the 'Model.Ingredients[i].Name'... truly baffled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Ingredients.Count; i++)
                    {
               <div class="form-group">
    <label class = "control-label col-md-2">Model.Ingredients[i].Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">

                        @Html.HiddenFor(ing => ing.Ingredients[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(ing => ing.Ingredients[i].Name)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Ingredients[i].IsSelected)
                        @Html.LabelFor(ing => ing.Ingredients[i].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(ing => ing.Ingredients[i].IsSelected, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })


                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: Yes mate! I needed to add the '@' before the  first
' Model.Ingredients[i].Name</label>' and then removed the @Html.LabelFor....    Cheers!